# Is SSL3 protocol supported in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

We are running windows 2019 Server Core OS image in our container. By default my container supports all the following protocols

```
TLS
TLS1.1
TLS1.2
```

My application is using ssl3 for some request. I want to enable ssl3 on the container

I tried editing the registry on container, but it requires a restart for windows to recognize change in registry related to ssl3. Since in docker, there is no concept of restarting windows inside container, how can I enable ssl3 protocol on windows docker 2019 image.
Can i use init containers for changing windows registry. If so, how?
I am also to any other options

Extra Information
I am using following command to know ssl3 is not there on windows 2019 Server OS container.

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 mysite.com --unprivileged
```

I am getting following output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL3 is not supported on Azure Containers